# Deserializing Json to get data directly and not through loop

Tags: c#, json

I see many different ways to deserialize Json and I think I am using the quickest method for my solution yet I have to do cartWheels to get to the data I want is there a better way to get the data I want from a JSON  object ?

```
private static void stillAttemptToParse()
{
    var client = new WebClient();
    var response = client.DownloadString(new Uri("http://localhost:52644/api/status"));

    var j = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Status>(response);
    //Status is a group of classes to represent the data from jsonToC#
    Console.WriteLine(j.OverallSuccess);

    foreach (var item in j.SettingItems)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("id: {0}, : {1} : {2}" , item.SettingName, item.Source , item.SettingValue);
    }
}
```

So the real question would be if i know the item.SettingsName is 'basicURL' how can I get the item.SettingsValue( which would be http://www.someBasicUrl.com )  for that item 'basicUrl' without running a loop ?

Comment: How is this JSON structured?  Can you paste a snippet of it?

Comment: Unless you show is the JSON you are parsing as @Amy suggests, there's no way for us to answer this. [`SelectToken`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenWithLinq.htm) might help.

Answer (score -2):

Take a look at Newtonsoft's json DeserializeObject(). Their Json.NET library is pretty good.

http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/deserializeobject.htm

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hello, and welcome to StackOverflow!  Please note that the question is already using this method: `var j = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Status>(response);`  What the OP seems to be asking for is a way to do this more conveniently, thus an answer to the question should suggest an alternative to simply calling `DeserializeObject`.  See [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).